# Full & complete uninstall QT Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator, debian-jessie

Question:

**How to uninstall QT Creator from Linux machine?**

I have a corrupted install on a Debian Jessie machine. I have tried reinstalling, fixing, etc. and with no luck. I was advised to uninstall completely, grab the newest version and reinstall.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to do this and every time I try, QT keeps coming back with the same exact issues, I'm assuming because of some config files that are not getting deleted in the removal process.

Running `qmake --version` gives me this output:

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.2 in /home/greg/anaconda2/lib
```

Running `pkg-config --modversion QtCore` gives me this output:

```
Package QtCore was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `QtCore.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'QtCore' found
```

The problem is that I've got several versions installed, in different folders and I want to completely start over with a fresh install of QT Creator. Version 5.10 was installed yesterday via the QT maintenence tool, but for some reason won't run. I just need to remove it and start over. QT 5.9.3 and 5.10 are installed at `/home/greg` and you can see 5.6.2 is installed in my anaconda2 folder. Not sure how this happened. I'm still a newb so still learning.

**How can I do a complete/full uninstall and removal of ALL QT creator files without deleting other QT files, such as KDE dependencies, etc., so that I can do a fresh install with new config settings????**

Comment: I know this is a few years old now, but this answer should be linked https://askubuntu.com/questions/257822/how-can-i-uninstall-qt5-that-i-installed-from-run

Answer (score 0):

*Qt Creator* creates some configuration files and subdirs in `~/.config/QtProject/` (also check `~/.config/Nokia/`), which aren't cleaned up by removing the package (in general that's the case with all personal settings in your home directory). Removing them manually should solve that issue, if your diagnosis is right and it's not a more general problem of your system or setup.