# build android application using qt

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, qml

I cannot run android application on android emulator, I got this error: Invalid json output from qmlimportscanner.
Every path are ok, without any space, jdk sdk and ndk are installed, so I really don't understand whye I got that error

Could someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: can you run your application on desktop environment ?

Comment: Hello, yes on desktop it works, it's a simple "analogclock"qt example;

Comment: very strange. can you try to run a simple empty program ? can you also try to run your program on a physical device ?

Comment: Around the web I see that this error sometimes mean space in folder path, ma I don't have any

Comment: No one can help me?

Comment: this may be helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189272/qt-creator-android-error-platform-sdk-installed/48348201#48348201