# Qt sdk Platforms not installed

Tags: android, c++, qt, sdk

Hello guys I have problem with sdk platforms. They are already installed, but Qt says that they are not installed. Can you help me please?

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

[image: Image4]

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189272/qt-creator-android-error-platform-sdk-installed

Comment: I have jdk10, so do you think that it will be fixed if I install jdk8?